# Sorting within password file linux

Tags: linux, sorting

I want to sort the linux passwd file by userid.

I tried

```
sort -k3 /etc/passwd
```

But my output isn't sorted by userid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option `-t` to set the field separator. Then, also use `-n` to sort numerically:

```
sort -n -t':' -k3 /etc/passwd
```

From `man sort`:

> **-t, --field-separator=SEP**
>
> use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition
>
> **-n, --numeric-sort**
>
> compare according to string numerical value

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/passwd` has `:` as the field separator.

```
sort -t: -k3 /etc/passwd
```